GCS NodeJS UploadManyFiles has unexpected behavior with the option 'skipIfExists'
I have an on-premise service (NodeJS) that runs every 5 minutes and uploads files to a Google Storage bucket. If the file has already been uploaded, it should be skipped in the next run. I noticed that TransferManager.UploadManyFiles() is way faster than uploading single files, so I want to use that. The 'UploadManyFilesOptions' has a field named 'skipIfExists'. But the behavior of that option is not as expected.
I have even tried to create a backup mechanism that uploads the files 1-by-1, but there the option 'skipIfExists' is not available at all. So there I would have to create my own logic as to whether the file already exists.
Expected/Wanted behavior:
If I upload 10 files, and 1 file already exsists, I expect the 1 file being silently ignored and the other 9 files to be uploaded. The response should either have 9 files (9 were uploaded) or 10 files (all 10 files are now in the bucket).
Actual behavior:
If I upload 10 files, and 1 file already exsists, I get an immediate error response without information as to which file or files have failed and no clue as to whether the other files have succeeded.
